# ASP Chart Control Hover Event showing X, Y Datapoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am using the ASP.NET chart control in C#. What I would like to get done is showing the X,Y datapoints when hovering over the chart from left to right.
Please use this link for an example:

http://de.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=^GDAXI#chart2:symbol=^gdaxi;range=5d;indicator=volume;charttype=line;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The chart in the link you posted is made in Flex. This allows you to get the datapoints. Doing this with the ASP.NET chart is going to be very difficult, if not impossible.